# Confusion about raising and lowering indices

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, notation

Is it possible to take the following expression:

$$U^\mu U^v\partial_\mu\partial_v$$

Where $U$ is the four-velocity, and simplify it the following way?:

$$U^\mu U^v \eta_{\mu v}\partial^v\partial_v =c^2\Box$$

$$(U^\mu U^v \eta_{\mu v}=c^2,\quad \partial^v\partial_v =\Box)$$

Comment: NO: If you introduce new dummy indexes, you should use a different letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Both $\mu$ and $\nu$ are already dummy indices. Remember that in the Einstein summation convention, each index may appear at most twice - once upstairs and once downstairs.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that
$$
\eta_{\mu\nu}~U^\mu~U^\nu=c^2
$$
in the ${+}{-}{-}{-}$ metric, there is no way to use that to reduce the expression you are starting with.

So for example you can align your $w=ct$ axis with $U^\mu$ at some point, and then $U^\mu~U^\nu~\partial_\mu~\partial_\nu$ at that point is just $\partial^2\over\partial w^2$. This is just obviously different than $\square$ which is $$\square={\partial^2\over\partial w^2}-
{\partial^2\over\partial x^2}-{\partial^2\over\partial y^2}-{\partial^2\over\partial z^2}
.$$